# Calculate percentages in Python (0% to100%)

Tags: python

At this code, I have a data with lots combinations from 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' and I am trying to find out how often each combination is existing.(example of the data: abdc, abcc, abcd, abbb, aaaa, abdc,...)
After that I want to have the answer in percentage from 0% to 100% of each letter combination. Also if it's zero.

Example Input:

```
letters: ['abc','aaa','abb','acc','aac','abc','bbb','ccc','ddd','abc','adc','acd','acd','aac','aad','bba','bab','abb','abc','abd'...]
```

I get df from this: ( tab_files is the file where get my data)

```
for i, tab_file in enumerate(tab_files):
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(tab_file, sep='\t')
```

Here is my try:

```
#letter_l = all combinations of letters (abcd) together
nt_l = "abcd"
letter_l = []
for i1 in nt_l:
    for i2 in nt_l:
        for i3 in nt_l:
            letter = i1+i2+i3
            letter_l.append(letter)
#print(letter_l)

#calculates the amount of each letter combination and shows the percentage
x = []
number_per_combination = {}
for b in letter_l:    
    counter = 0
    number_per_combination[b] = 0
    for c2 in df.letter:
        if c2 == b:
           counter +=1
           number_per_combination[b] += 1
 # amount of each letter combination divided through the whole amount
    x.append(counter/(len(df.letter)))
```

but I get strange percentages as answer... I don't understand why. Can somebody help me?

```
Output I want:     number_per combination
'abc': 20%        (40)
'aaa': 10%        (20)
'ccd': 0%         (0)
'ddd': 3%         (6)...
```

Comment: can you give any sample o/p ?

Comment: Where is `df` defined?

Comment: What is this code even tries to achieve? Provide a **simple** input and expected output. This whole code can probably be refactored to less than 5 lines of code using `itertools` and `Counter`

Answer (score 0):

So what you're trying to do is a histogram? Here's a simple way to do it:

```
input_list = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c']

def histogram(my_list):
    result = {}
    for item in my_list:
        result[item] = result.get(item, 0) + 1
    return result

print(str(histogram(input_list)))
```

The .get() method returns the value for the given key from the dictionary. If the key isn't there, it is inserted and given the value provided in the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import itertools

data="aaa, abc, aab"
words = re.split(', ',data)
words_count = {}
total_count = len( words )

for word in list(itertools.product(["a","b","c","d"], repeat=3)):
  words_count["".join(word)] = 0

for word in words:
  words_count[word] = words_count.get(word,0) + 1

for word in words_count:
  p = words_count[word]/total_count * 100
  print( "%s: %.3f%%\t(%d)" % (word,p,words_count[word]) )
```